# Java code to get android phone hardware specs

Tags: android

Is there code available to view the specs of a phone that is running your application?

Comment: How is this related to game development?

Comment: What exactly do you want to detect? The existence of a front camera? The amount of memory available?

Comment: It may not be directly related to game dev, but it is needed for my game.  Yes, processor, memory... things like that

Comment: Someone should warn you that whatever you are trying to do with this information that you claim is "needed" for your game is probably not the right way to accomplish your goals.

Comment: -1 You are asking for code, which should not be done here. Try posting your question here http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: You should not ask for code here? Since when?

Comment: @roe He could be writing an android game and is trying to auto tune his game for the amount of memory he is allowed to allocate.

Comment: @stonemetal; sure he could, but that's only borderline game development, and much more simply android programming (i.e. more appropriate for stackoverflow)

Comment: Eh I figure true that stackoverflow is for code and android development. But gamedev.stackexchange.com is for game development.  It can be code, concepts, or whatever game related.  So that makes this a perfectly relevant place to post this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a built in class you can use.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html

Also you might like to checkout PhoneGap.java for some other useful tidbits.

http://code.google.com/p/phonegap/source/browse/trunk/android/src/com/nitobi/phonegap/PhoneGap.java

Comment: Thanks.  This is what I was looking for.  I can't get direct specs, but the phone models are enough to get what I need.